# comparing Unicode strings?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7

Basically what I am trying to do is compare `"✔" == "✔"` in Python (2.7). But I keep receiving this error, `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'`. I read the Python docs but the whole Unicode, encoding, and decoding thing is confusing me a lot..

**EDIT**

I fixed the problem by comparing what should be the ✔ against `\u2714`, which is check marks character code (I think that is what you would call it?).

Comment: I suspect you want `u"✔" == u"✔"`

Comment: Actually the first one is from a web page I am scrapping with BeautifulSoup and is checking if it is a ✔ or ?

Comment: @DrHydralisk: (a) Update your question (b) Your scenario is quite different from your question. Maybe the answers so far can help you figure out how.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't specified what charset the file uses, so Python defaults to ASCII and fails with a `SyntaxError` as soon as it encounters the unicode characters. Adding this at the very beginning of the file should fix that:

```
# coding:utf-8
```

More info here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Answer (score 0):

Works at my side:

```
[avasal@avasal]$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "✔" == "✔"
True
>>> u"✔" == u"✔"
True
>>>
```

Comment: This is because the interpreter is not the same as reading from a file